# row level security and check duplicate

Tags: spring, postgresql

I create an application with spring boot and Postgresql. I use Row Level Security of posgresql to "secure/limit" the data of connected user.
(I use JdbcInterceptor to add "set role" on each session and "reset role" after)

My problem:
I want to check duplicate before insert and duplicate can be on data which user cannot see.
For exemple, user can only access to his email, he can create a new email, but before create, if want to check if email doesn't exist in the database.

Do you have an idea how i can do that?

Comment: I find it hard to understand what you are trying to do. Can you provide more details - specifics, tables, queries, etc?

Comment: When admin is connected, he can see all user in table user.
When "manager1" is connected, he can see only user of "customer1".

I do that with Row Level Security. I create a role "customer1", and a policy on table "user" which says "using (current_user = customer_id)".

When "manager1" try to do "/api/users" on my api, JdbcInterceptor intercept the session and add: set role "customer1", and postgresql return only users of "customer1".

On my UI (angular), when "manager1" create a new user, i want to check if (the login for exemple) doesn't exist in all DB before the insert

Comment: Just insert it and trap the error. See `WITH CHECK OPTION`.

Comment: It's a solution, but i need to check before the insert (for ergonomic reasons )

Comment: You can't. Pretty much by design, since you could then see the record and thus bypass RLS. What you probably need is column masking or per-column RLS, where you can say "users can see the id of rows they don't own but no other fields". This is not yet supported by RLS.